# Simple add function returns NaN

Tags: javascript, html, function

This is my code:

```js
var i=5;
var j=5;

function sum(n,m){
  var num = n + m ;
  alert(num);

};

sum(i+j);
```

> When I run it, it should return '10', but it returns `NaN`.

Please help me with what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `i+j` evaluates to `10`, so `sum(i+j)` becomes `sum(10)`. This results in the second argument not being passed...

Comment: you are also not returning anything... but that isn't the problem. you will need to eventually `return num;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it from `sum(i + j)` to `sum(i, j)`. So technically your code was passing originally like `sum(10, undefined)` which resolved as `NaN`.

```js
var i=5;
var j=5;

function sum(n,m){
  var num = n + m ;
  alert(num);

};

sum(i, j);
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I figured what I was doing wrong.

this below code works -

```
var i=5;
var j=5;

function sum(n,m){
  var num = n + m ;
  alert(num);

};

sum(i, j);
```